# Measuring Network Throughput Java/Android

Tags: java, android, http, networking

I'm doing an App for Android, and want to measure the network throughput using HTTP.
So far have done the code that makes the HTTP GET to the www.google.pt page.
I measure the time between before and after the request.

The Problem: I'm measuring the time of the entire data exchange between the server and my app, with all the overhead of the TCP Protocol. I need to get only the time that takes my app to receive only the webpage (useful data).

I have used wireshark to see what happens during the request.
The useful data are the PDU's that you see. That's what i want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GObIO.jpg

http://tinypic.com/r/15u6og/8

```
public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Time Functions Before
            Calendar calendarBefore = Calendar.getInstance();// instance class Calendar
            int millisecondsBefore = calendarBefore.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // Time Functions After
            Calendar calendarAfter = Calendar.getInstance();// instance class Calendar
            int millisecondsAfter = calendarAfter.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

            // Time Difference Calculation
            int timeDiff = millisecondsAfter - millisecondsBefore;

            String timeDifference = new String(); // time difference (After-Before)

            //Verify the signal of the timeDifference value
            if(timeDiff < 0){
                timeDiff = timeDiff * (-1); // reverse the signal in the operation
                timeDifference=Integer.toString(timeDiff);
            }
            else{
                timeDifference=Integer.toString(timeDiff);                  
            }


            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert input stream to string

            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream, timeDiff);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So, i'm measuring a lot of things that i don't need. I need to measure the time that takes to receive those PDU's.

If you guys know anything that can help me, would help me a lot. If you have any other suggestion, would love to hear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {


            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

           //Get Bytes of data Consumed
           long oldCount = android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

             //Get Bytes of data Consumed
             long newCount = android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

            //GetTotalData Consumed
            Log.i("totalDataConsumption",(newCount-oldCount)+" Bytes");

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert input stream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream, timeDiff);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and the newCount and oldCount have the same value. The totalDataConsumption has 0 Bytes. And even with this i'm not able to measure the time that takes to receive the data. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Hey, this only works for Mobile Data. I have a value and now i'm going to see if i can work on it. Then i will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Also try this android.net.TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()

Comment: I'm still trying to achieve a proper result. I think it could work. I'm trying to use an AsyncTask to test in a loop the amount of data received and measure the time interval while the HttpRequest is being executed. After the execution of the HttpRequest the AsyncTask is stopped. I'm having a little problem but i will make it. But i'm using the code that you gave me. If this fails to achieve what i want i think i will have to try FTP to measure throughput. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnMurhy Please keep me posted on the same.

Comment: Hi, i tried to do what i told you, and it's running perfectly, but, the values that i get at the end aren't good enough to measure accurately throughput, actually, way off. Thank you so much for your help. By the way you think that i could use FTP to download a file from a server and measure the throughput? There are public servers that allows any client to download a file? Thank you again!

Comment: did you use getTotalRxBytes() or getMobileRxBytes()?
And were some other internet based apps/services running on the test device simultaneously other than your app?

Comment: I used getMobileRxBytes(), because that's what i need, only mobile. No there were no other apps running simultaneously. Actually the values are similar to the ones that i analyzed in the wireshark tests. I'm trying FTP now. Seeing if i can get an accurate result. Thanks!

Comment: How about converting the downloaded stream into a byte array and then detecting its size. This way you can exactly know how much data has been downloaded. You can easily use bytes to KB conversion to detect number of KBs downloaded.